# Oracle String concatenation for multiple columns with grouping

Tags: string, oracle, concatenation, grouping

My Table data looks like:

```
SupID      SystemName    TermID
================================
Sup1       Sys1           23
Sup1       Sys1           12
Sup1       Sys2           10
Sup1       Sys2           11
Sup1       Sys2           15
Sup2       Sys2           22
Sup2       Sys3           12
Sup2       sys3           16
Sup3       Sys4           45
```

And I need to be display the data as below:

```
SupID      SystemName    TermID
================================
Sup1      Sys1:Sys2     23,12:10,11,15
Sup2      Sys2:Sys3     22:12,16
Sup3      Sys4          45
```

Using `t_string_agg()` function I am able to get the data in desired  format, but `SystemName` and `TermID` values are not in same Order.

Eg, I am getting below result:

```
SupID     SystemName    TermID
================================
Sup1      Sys2:Sys1     23,12:10,11,15
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: The `t_string_agg()` function does not exist in Oracle... there are plenty of user-defined and inbuilt functions that do though... but they're version dependent. Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi Ben, I am using Oracle10g and I have defined t_string_agg() function similar to LISTAGG() function in oracle11g.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle 11, the [`LISTAGG` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) will do this for you:

```
SELECT
  SupID,
  LISTAGG(SystemName, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SystemName) AS SystemNameList,
  LISTAGG(TermID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TermID) AS TermIDList
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY SupID
ORDER BY SupID
```

This query will order the `SystemName` list  by `SystemName`, and it will order the `TermID` list by `TermName`.

Your requested output doesn't have the lists sorted. The `ORDER BY` in `LISTAGG` is required, so if you really do want to avoid sorting just order by something harmless like `SupID` or `NULL`:

```
LISTAGG(TermID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SupID) AS TermIDList
```

*or*

```
LISTAGG(TermID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS TermIDList
```

That may or may not work. Oracle will determine the sort order, and if you're really, really lucky it will come out the way you want :)

Or if you have another column that determines the order (such as a PK or a timestamp) just use that.

Comment: Thanks Gibbs, I am using oracle10g, So I can't use LISTAGG() function. I am using similar user defined function t_string_agg() which I found on web. But I am not able to use t_string_agg() function with WITHIN GROUP clause.

Comment: Yes, the `WITHIN GROUP` would be specific to `LIST_AGG`. 10g may have a built-in (but undocumented and therefore unsupported) function named `WM_CONCAT`. There's information about it [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).